# How can I display a tooltip over objects in SQL Server Management Studio when hover on them

Tags: sql, sql-server, object, tooltip, ssms

I have a task to display a custom definition of the SP's or any other objects I may use in SQL Server Management Studio when I hover on these objects when I write them in Management Studio

Comment: Unless you want to go all the way of writing an SSMS **plugin** (and I'm not even sure you can do it then...) - there's no way to do this ....

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the capability for definitions/tool tips on hovering is supported.

As a workaround, this may be helpful to see the custom definition of a sproc (Stored Procedure) in SQL Server Management Studio (SMSS), this might be helpful.

Note: This is pulled straight from MSDN and should apply to SQL Server 2012 and beyond, but I think should also work in 2008, as well:

> ### Using SQL Server Management Studio
>
> **To view the definition a procedure in Object Explorer**
>
> 1. In Object Explorer, connect to an instance of Database Engine and then expand that instance.
> 2. Expand **Databases**, expand the database in which the procedure belongs, and then expand **Programmability**.
> 3. Expand **Stored Procedures**, right-click the procedure and then click **Script Stored Procedure** as, and then click one of the following: **Create To**, **Alter To**, or **Drop and Create To.**
> 4. Select **New Query Editor Window**. This will display the procedure definition.

For documentation on doing this using T-SQL (in the query editor), check  out the SQL Server documentation on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345443.aspx).